# Emacs, ENSIME and SBT

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

I'm running Emacs + ENSIME and using sbt in an emacs window (M-x term) to compile and run tests.  Is there any way to click/select to jump to the failing tests?  At the moment I have to scroll up a long way to find what failed, then open the right file and go to the line number.  Seems likely there is an easier way.

(Long term eclipse user trying to convert to emacs for Scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't install sbt.el: this functionality is built into ensime. Instead of running sbt in a shell, use

```
M-x ensime-sbt
```

This will find the project for the source file you are in and turn on the detection of error-messages automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Emacs+Ensime does it, but the following Emacs plugin for sbt can parse compiler error results, so clicking on the error message jumps to an appropriate position in the failing source file.

https://github.com/stevej/emacs/blob/master/support/sbt.el

I believe that failing tests do not produce information about the file and the line number (but this depends what kind of tests you're running). If they could, perhaps this plugin could work, or be augmented to work..

Comment: Nice plugin.  Good point about the line number, I forgot that I only got the number from careful inspection of the stack trace.